# Woocommerce product data export NULL data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress Woocommerce build and I am exporting completed orders to a json endpoint. I have code in functions.php that fires once an order is completed. All of the order data is is working but no matter what I do I can't get the product information. The data always shows as NULL in my json array.

Every product data loop I try will not bring in any part of the product data, it simply returns blank or NULL in the json data. I am using the base woocommerce template and there are no other plugins used.

I cant use the WP webhooks(I wishI could) because I need to add additional fields and change the  field names in the export.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_sample');

function send_sample($order_id){

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$order_number= $order->get_order_number();
$payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
$firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
$LastName = $order->get_billing_last_name();
$OrderDate= $order->get_date_created();
$ordertotal=$order->get_total();
$phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
$address1 = $order->get_billing_address_1();
$address2 = $order->get_billing_address_2();
$city = $order->get_billing_city();

$products = array (); 
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

   // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
    $product        = $item->get_product();
    $active_price   = $product->get_price(); // The product active raw price
    $regular_price  = $product->get_sale_price(); // The product raw sale price
    $sale_price     = $product->get_regular_price(); // The product raw regular price
    $product_name   = $item->get_name(); // Get the item name (product name)
    $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
    $item_subtotal  = $item->get_subtotal(); // Get the item line total non discounted
    $item_subto_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Get the item line total tax non discounted
    $item_total     = $item->get_total(); // Get the item line total discounted
    $item_total_tax = $item->get_total_tax(); // Get the item line total  tax discounted
    $item_taxes     = $item->get_taxes(); // Get the item taxes array
    $item_tax_class = $item->get_tax_class(); // Get the item tax class
    $item_tax_status= $item->get_tax_status(); // Get the item tax status
    $item_downloads = $item->get_item_downloads(); // Get the item downloads

 //   Displaying this data (to check)
  // echo 'Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.' | Item total: '. number_format( $item_total, 2 );
   array_push($products,$product_name);

}



$bouhajir= array (
  'password' => '1234',
  'email' => 'ms@bt.com',
  'fielddata' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'hub' => 'DCLC',
      'awbNo' => "'$order_number'",
      'merchantCode' => 'xyz',
      'merchantName' => 'xyz name',
      'date' => "$OrderDate",
      'jobType' => 'FWD',
      'jobData' =>
      array (
        'city' => "$city",
        'contact_number_change_test' => "$phone",
        'name' => "$firstname"." "."$LastName",
        'weight' => 0.8,
        'slot' => '',
        'collectables_amount' => "$ordertotal",
        'pincode' => '',
        'payment_choice' => "$payment_method",
        'product_image' => '',
        'address' => "$address1"." "."$address2",
        'order_number' => "'$order_number'",
      //  'contents' => "$item_name"." "."$quantity",
        'packet_count' => 1,
        'item_description' => 'this is just a dummy description',
        'remarks' => 'handle with care',
        'dl_no' => 'dddfdas',
      ),
          'testdata' =>
      array (
$products     ),
     
    ),
  ),
);


$datasend= json_encode ($bouhajir);

###send code ommitted###
```

Comment: use this hook instead woocommerce_order_status_completed

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried changing the hook but still received no data. Do you have any other suggestions I could try.

Comment: Apologies, it is working. I just noticed my order was set to processing so the hook didn't fire when I changed the hook. Is there a hook for when the order is completed at the checkout that will fire.

Comment: You can use the "woocommerce_checkout_order_processed" hook.

Comment: I will give that a go, thanks for your help, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Enjoy your life!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note for anyone facing a similar issue: It is possible to customize custom values with WP Webhooks by using its [Data Mapping](https://wp-webhooks.com/docs/article-categories/data-mapping/) feature, as well as the [Flows](https://wp-webhooks.com/docs/article-categories/flows/) feature.

In case the fields really require further formatting, it might also be an option to take a look at the [Custom Trigger called](https://wp-webhooks.com/integrations/wordpress/triggers/custom_action/) webhook as it allows you to send a completely customized payload to your endpoint.

If you totally want to go with some predefined webhook trigger, but you cannot find a way of validating the data via any of the above/mentioned features, you still have the option to [manipulate the webhook payload](https://wp-webhooks.com/docs/knowledge-base/filter-webhook-trigger-data/) of the request itself.